# How to add frames to an audio stream in real-time to time-stretch the audio

Tags: swift, audio, spotify, core-audio

I need to access an unsafeRawPointer which points to an audio buffer, in this case from Spotify iOS SDK.  Then I want to add frames to that buffer and return it do the super.method as expected.  The result should be a time-stretched (slowed down) audio without pitch distortion.  I can't seem to make it work.I commented out a few attempts...I thought getting into an array and adding adding items to the array would do it...but when I try to return it to the method...the audio gets corrupted.  Please help. I've been trial and erroring for weeks now.  :-(

```
class CoreAudioController: SPTCoreAudioController {

  override func attempt(toDeliverAudioFrames audioFrames: UnsafeRawPointer!, ofCount frameCount: Int, streamDescription audioDescription: AudioStreamBasicDescription) -> Int {
  print("attempt to deliver audio frames")


  var pointer: UnsafePointer<Int16> = audioFrames.bindMemory(to: Int16.self, capacity: byteCount)

  // Attemping to add empty frames to space out the audio frames then return the expected pointer below...

  // let framePointer = UnsafeRawBufferPointer(start: pointer, count: byteCount)
  // var framePointer = UnsafeBufferPointer(start: pointer, count: frameCount)
  // var frames = Array(framePointer)

  // withUnsafePointer(to: &frames) { bytes in
  //
  //    }


    return super.attempt(toDeliverAudioFrames: pointer, ofCount: frameCount, streamDescription: audioDescription)
  }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how this can easily be done manually, but libraries such as Superpowered.com have several tools to alter audio feeds in real time.  I've used it in my app (Piti Piti Pa) to do live audio mixing of up to 20 instruments.

In particular, you would be interested in using the SuperpoweredTimeStretching class: https://superpowered.com/docs/class_superpowered_time_stretching.html

Hopefully someone can provide useful information that will require less integration work, but I hope the information above may be of use to you or someone else.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I would be very welcome to using a library. For some reason my research led me to believe most of these don't support working with either Spotify and/or streaming audio.  Does Superpowered work with Spotify streaming?

Comment: it supports a few online stream protocols not sure about spotify.  But you can use it to manipulate the raw audio samples you would typically push to AudioKit so I’m pretty sure it will be of use to you

Comment: looked at superpowered. I couldn't even understand how to install it.  AudioKit gives me CocoaPod support. Makes me think superpowered will be hard to use and find support if I can't even figure out how to install. They do provide Sample projects which I got working. I suspect going throught the header bridging steps...but it would be nice if they at least had a tutorial.

Comment: Looking at those examples is how I got started with it.  I love its simplicity, it seems a lot harder than it really is; but yes, you need a good understanding of programming to use it.